# Rack::Session::Pool Sessions in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

I can't seem to get these sessions to continue into other pages.

app.rb:

```
    class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
        use Rack::Session::Pool, :expire_after => 60 * 1

        get "/" do
            @foo = "one two three"
            erb :index
        end

        get "/first" do
            session[:foo] = Time.now
            session[:message] = "ALPHA"
            session[:message1] = "CHARLIE"

            erb :first
        end

        get "/second" do
            session[:message2] = "BRAVO2"

            erb :second
        end
    end
```

Inside /first and /second:

```
Sess: <%= session.inspect %><br>
```

The session doesn't want to carry across pages.  On /first I'm displaying this:

```
Sess: {"message"=>"ALPHA", "message1"=>"CHARLIE", "foo"=>2015-12-01 17:05:31 -0500}
```

On /second I'm displaying this:

```
Sess: {"message2"=>"BRAVO2"}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you starting the app? Are you using `shotgun` or something similar?

Comment: It's on Passenger.  require File.expand_path('app', File.dirname(__FILE__))
run MyApp

Comment: That might explain it. I suspect each request is being routed to a different Ruby process by Passenger, so the session (stored in process) isn’t available in the second request. Try running your app directly with `rackup` and see if it works there.

Comment: I just renamed always_restart.txt and the session is carrying from /first to /second, but /third doesn't show the session.  It only has the erb file :third and nothing else.  Do I have to call something to carry that through?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know – I’ve reached the limit of my knowledge about Passenger. (There’s no `third` route in your question btw.)

Answer (score 1):

Just needed a restart.  Figure that.